# merging two files into a new file

Tags: r

I have 2 files with say 3 columns and a few rows.

```
1    2    10
2    3    20
3    4    30
4    5    40
5    1    50
6    1    60
```

and

```
1    8    10
2    3    100
3    4    45
4    5    78
5    2    99
6    80   60
```

Now i want to create a third file having all the values of first two files and also if first and second column of both the files are same then in third file the values corresponding to them should like say,value in  third column of first file must be in third column of newly created file and value in third column of second file must be in fourth column of newly created file.
According to above example answer should be

```
1  2  10  0
2  3  20  100
3  4  30  45
4  5  40  78
1  8  10   0
5  1  50   0
6  1  60   0
5  2  99   0
6  80 60   0
```

Comment: After looking at your expected result, I think the code I gave you is incorrect.  Regarding the warning message, check if you are columns are `factors` by `str(dat1)`

Comment: Why you don't have the row `1 8 10 0` in the expected result

Comment: i used str(df1). Output was 'data.frame': 7 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 7 1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ V2: Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 6 2 3 4 5 1 1
 $ V3: Factor w/ 7 levels "10","20","30",..: 7 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention.

Comment: It is better to change the columns to `numeric` class.  `dat1[] <- lapply(dat1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` and same for `dat2` before you merge

Comment: I tried to replicate the problem in the data I posted with `factor` column.  Didn't get any warnings though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 res <- merge(dat1,dat2, by=c("V1", "V2"),all=TRUE)
 indx <- is.na(res[,3]) 
 res[indx,3] <- res[indx,4]
 res[indx,4] <- NA
 res[is.na(res)] <- 0
 #    V1 V2 V3.x V3.y
 #1  1  2   10    0
 #2  1  8   10    0
 #3  2  3   20  100
 #4  3  4   30   45
 #5  4  5   40   78
 #6  5  1   50    0
 #7  5  2   99    0
 #8  6  1   60    0
 #9  6 80   60    0
```

#### data

```
 dat1 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
 "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 
 5L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
V3 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("10", "20", "30", "40", "50", 
"60"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

 dat2 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
 "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(5L, 2L, 3L, 
 4L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "8", "80"), class = "factor"), 
V3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("10", 
"100", "45", "60", "78", "99"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Convert the data columns to `numeric` class before you try the above code

```
dat1[] <- lapply(dat1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))) 
dat2[] <- lapply(dat2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you post an example with `dput()`. I would check if `?merge` helps or `rbind.fill` (package `plyr`).
Hope this helps
Hermann

Comment: d3 <- merge(d1, d2, by=c('V1','V2')). I used this but as you know it will  output only the common ones, however what i need is a new file with the non-common ones as well.

Comment: @AmbikaGupta, You need to add `all = T`, but I'm still struggling understanding your desired output. Where is `V1 = 1` `V2 = 8` combination for example?

Comment: See all=TRUE and all.x and all.y ... "These rows will have ‘NA’s in those columns that are usually filled with values from ‘y’.  The default is ‘FALSE’,so that only rows with data from both ‘x’ and ‘y’ are." Something like merge(d1,d2, by=..., all=TRUE) should work. Than you just have to replace NA with 0 if you want.

Comment: Thank you but  its showing warnings when tried to replace NA with 0